# is it possible to share data of localstorage between tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have two domains and I need to pass localstorage data from domain A to domain B when execute a botton of the extension that i'm creating?

Comment: You can copy the data in your first tab's content script to chrome.storage.local and then read it in the second tab. You can also use chrome.runtime messaging via the background script. For further assistance please show [MCVE](/help/mcve) with your code.

Comment: i was following that example but  i need to send a value from localstorage of domain A to domain B as variable or another because i need that value for making a request to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `chrome.storage.local`. Content scripts in all tabs can access `chrome.storage.local`.

So, content script in Domain A tab:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
  fromDomainA: window.localStorage.getItem('fromDomainA')
});
```

In contentScript on Domain B tab:

```
const fromDomainA = await chrome.storage.local.get('fromDomainA');
console.log(fromDomainA);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my example. First i created a button in popup.html that execute a message to content-script.

```
document.getElementById("syncronize").onclick = function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello" }, () => {});
  });
};
```

then i need to get the value of localstorage from domain A to send to the domain B. i send other message to background

```
console.log("localstorage", localStorage);
console.log("sessionStorage", sessionStorage);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting == "hello") {
    console.log(request, sender, "from the extension");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      { method: "send", value: localStorage.getItem("token") },
      (response) => {
        console.log("messasage contentScript", response);
      }
    );
  }
  sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
  return true;
});
```

final in the background file i listen the message and assign the value to the global var but i don't sure if the context of the background file is only to the domain A.

Can i get that value to domain B?
i need to pass that token from domain A to the domain B